# How did people lose or gain āshramic adhikāras?

Tags: puranas, brahmacharya, varnashrama, upanayanam, ashram

> Not everyone has to go through all the 4 stages – Brahmacharya, Grihastha, Vanaprastha and Parivrajaka.

> A Shudra can only lead the 2nd phase (Grihastha) and is not entitled for the other three phases of life.
> A Vaishya can only lead the 1st (Brahmacharya) and 2nd phase (Grihastha) and is not entitled to lead the other two phases of life.
> A Khastriya can only lead the 1st (Brahmacharya), 2nd (Grihastha) and 3rd phase (Vanaprastha) and is not entitled to lead the “Parivrajaka” phase of life.
> A Brahmin is entitled to lead all the 4 phases of life.

Source: https://www.lonelyphilosopher.com/stages-in-a-mans-life-and-duties-in-each-stage/

1. Why do Brāhmanas poses all adhikāras as mentioned above?
2. Do Devtās too have adhikāras as such throughout their existence span?
3. How did people lose the adhikāras and become Kshatriya, Vaishya or Shudra if it's the case that each one of them originally descended from Lord Brahmā, what's the justification and where did it all began?
4. Is it possible to deduce the timelines from scriptural sources for the same?

Comment: 1. because they severely restrict their sense-enjoyment in previous births and that's why they get brahmin birth in this life. if a shudra or kshatriya tried to take sanyasa, his mind would be in torture due to unfulfilled desires. it's just a step-by-step promotion method that bhagavan has created. of course you can try to jump 10 steps in one shot, very few exceptions might succeed, but most would fall and break their head and go even lower than where they started with.